# 406 on loading of script from my mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my mvc application I am getting 406 when my cshtml file tries to load the js file.
something like this

```
GET http://localhost/Scripts/App/Dashboard.js?_=1408764995728
406 Not Acceptable
```

Request Header's says:
Accept: application/json

Whereas Response header says;
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

If I run the same on a postman I get the result with response header as 
Content-Type →application/javascript

Any clue on this.

Comment: show us the Dashboard.js file.

Comment: This was happening due to header being explicitly specified with json accept type for few cases of flow.

Comment: are you passing json data?

Answer (score 0):

Please, first check what is Asp.net [content negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation):

> “the process of selecting the best
>   representation for a given response when there are multiple
>   representations available.”

Most probably you get HTTP error 406 (Not Acceptable) because no formatter has been found for format that was specified in your request's headers (application/json).

- You can loop through all registered formatters (GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters) and check if there is formatter for application/json.
- register json formatter.